# Javascript App works fine...and then it doesn't

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

This question probably won't fit into the Stack Exchange guidelines because of a number of factors, so bare with me.

I have built a GIS web app at http://matthewiannowlin.com/planning/thesis. I used the JavaScript API. At a certain point, a problem started showing up where about 4 out of 5 times, the Esri stuff won't load. So the map and all the widgets. If I refresh enough times I'll finally get the whole page to load. Then it works perfectly.

When I look at console log, I see this error on the times Esri widgets don't load:

[Error] TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'e.renderer.toLowerCase')

ia (init.js, line 33)

fa (init.js, line 33)

g (init.js, line 35)

(anonymous function) (init.js, line 40)

I don't even know what to ask, I'm afraid. Besides...what the hell? I feel like this became a problem as the code become more complex and/or as I called more widgets.

Here are some random thoughts: does this have something to do with the timing of how things are load? Does this somehow relate to dojo/ready or dojo/DomReady? Or parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured this out. Using Ariel Flesler's jQuery scrollTo plugin conflicted with something in the dojo code that ArcGIS was using in its JavaScript API.

So now I just need to figure out how to smooth scroll to a div in a way that doesn't conflict with the API code.